# Question regarding the roots of $x^2 + nx + m$, for $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: proof-explanation, roots, quadratics

> The equation $x^2+nx+m=0$, $n,m\in\mathbb Z$, cannot have
>
> A. Integral roots
> B. Non-integral roots
> C. Irrational roots
> D. Complex roots

Please explain also....

Comment: Does 'Integral roots' mean a root which is an integer?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Rational_Root_Theorem

Comment: The question is poorly written. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try to do for a problem like this is write down some explicit values of $(m,n)$, and see what happens!

How I'd approach this problem in particular is try to craft equations that *have* the roots that we want to show it can't have.

A. Integral roots:

We want $x^2 + nx + m$ to have integral roots.
One easy root to give it is $x = 0$, by setting $m = 0$.
$x^2 + nx = x(x+n)$ has roots $x,-n$, for any choice of $n$.
So A clearly isn't true!

B. Non-integral roots

You can try this for various values, and you might struggle to find rational roots.
This doesn't *prove* that this is the answer, but it's good to note for sure.

C. Irrational roots

If we set $n = 0$, we get the equation $x^2 + m = 0$, and by choosing $m < 0$ we can $\sqrt{k}$ as a root (for any $k$ we want!).
For example, $x^2 -2$ has root $\sqrt{2}$.
This clearly isn't the choice then.

D. Imaginary roots

If we again set $n = 0$, but instead choose $m > 0$, we'll get imaginary roots!
We can use the equation $x^2 + 1$, to get $i$ as a root!

---

The above makes it seem like B. should be the answer.
We might then wonder *why* $B$ should be the answer.
Someone else already mentioned the Rational Root test, which gives an easy answer as to why.
A more *qualitative* way to see this is by trying to build an equation of your form that has a rational root!

Let the two roots of our equation be $r_1 = p/q$, and $r_2$ which can be *anything*.
Then, our equation is:

$$(x - p/q)(x - r_2) = 0 \implies (qx-p)(x-r_2) = 0 \implies qx^2 - (r_2q +p)x + pr_2 = 0\implies x^2 - \frac{r_2q+p}{q}x + \frac{pr_2}{q} = 0$$

We now just need $(r_2q+p)/q$ and $pr_2/q$ to be integral.
We can "force" the second one to be integral by making $r_2$ a multiple of $q$ (say $r_2 = kq$ for some integer $k$).
But then we have that $(kq^2+p)/q$ needs to be an integer, which it won't be.

If we instead want to force $(r_2q+p)/q$ to be an integer, we could say that we'll set $r_2$ such that $r_2q+p = kq$ for some integer $k$.
This is the same as saying that $p = (k-r_2)q$, which unfortunately isn't allowed at first (While I didn't explicitly say so, generally when you write a rational number as $p / q$ you assume that $p$ and $q$ are coprime, so have no common factors.
The equation I just wrote down shows that $q$ is a common factor, which would imply that $p / q$ was integral all along).

Comment: Non-integral roots include irrational roots, which is why I consider this a poor question. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The entire nature of the roots depends upon auxiliary equation ie.,$n^2-4m$ let us call it as AE Case-1$AE >0$ the root maybe an integer or a surd ex:-$(x^2-3x+2)(1,2),(x^2-3x+1)(1{^+_-}\frac{\sqrt5}2)$ case-2if$AE =0$  the roots are integer and equal ex:-$(x^2+2x+1)(1,1)$ case-3 if $AE <0$ roots are imaginary and complex conjugates to each other ex:- $(x^2-2x+3)(1{^+_-}i\sqrt2),(x^2-2x+5)(1{^+_-}i2),(x^2+1)({^+_-}i).$

Answer (score 0):

As it is written currently, your question has no correct answer.

A. $n=2, m=1$ is a counterexample.

C. $n=1, m=-1$ is a counterexample.

D. $n=m=1$ is a counterexample.

That leaves B. Non-integers include irrational numbers, so if C is false, then so is B.

To allow the question to be answerable, B has to be rephrased to "non-integral rational roots". In which case, B would be the correct response.

To see why this is the case, consider the solution by the general quadratic formula $x = \frac 12(-n\pm \sqrt{n^2-4m})$. We are considering only cases where $n^2-4m$ is a perfect square, otherwise the roots would be irrational. Now $n$ has to be either even or odd. If $n$ were even, $\sqrt{n^2-4m}$ would be even as would $-n\pm \sqrt{n^2-4m}$ so the roots would be integral. If $n$ were odd, then $\sqrt{n^2-4m}$  would be odd and hence $-n\pm \sqrt{n^2-4m}$ would be even, again rendering the roots integral. There is no way to construct non-integral rational roots.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/151732/deepak thanks for your help, it was the best way to tackle this situation. And you are right, it's non-integral rational roots but someone edited it.....